# ManyToManyFields in Django Admin

Tags: django, django-admin

I'm using Photologue in my application, and I really like the `ManyToManyField` selector that appears in the admin app (two multi-select boxes with arrows for moving items between the selected and non-selected states, along with "Choose All" and "Clear All" options).

I'm using very similar code in my own model, but my `ManyToManyField` selector just shows up as a normal `<select multiple="multiple" ...>` field. I can't see anything special in Photologue's `admin.py` or `models.py`, and the two apps are running in the same project.

My model:

```
class Portfolio(models.Model):
    images      = models.ManyToManyField(Photo, related_name='portfolios')
    ...
```

Relevant model from Photologue:

```
class Gallery(models.Model):
    ....
    photos = models.ManyToManyField('Photo',
                                    related_name='galleries',
                                    verbose_name=_('photos'),
                                    null=True, blank=True)
```

Admin from Photologue:

```
class GalleryAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    list_display = ('title', 'date_added', 'photo_count', 'is_public')
    list_filter = ['date_added', 'is_public']
    date_hierarchy = 'date_added'
    prepopulated_fields = {'title_slug': ('title',)}
    filter_horizontal = ('photos',)
```

Anyone know what I'm missing? I'll post screenshots if it would help.

Thanks,

Dom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See django docs for [filter_horizontal](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.filter_horizontal)

> a nifty unobtrusive JavaScript "filter" interface instead of the usability-challenged <select multiple> in the admin form.

Comment: Silly me - that's right there in the question - it just didn't look like it could be the relevant bit of the admin declaration. Thanks!